# A program is executed by the OS or the IDE ?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, memory, operating-system

ex: 
A .c program after compilation is executed with Visual Studio 2013(F5). Is VS involved in executing the program? Is the .c program run within the memory acquired by the Visual Studio Program? Or will the OS allocate a different section of memory. If so,is VS out of the picture while executing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ".c" file is compiled to a PE executable file on Windows. These are the usual programs with the typical ".exe" file extension.

When you press F5 in Visual Studio, it launches this executable file by using the WinAPI (for example `CreateProcess`). These WinAPI calls go up to the OS which creates a new process with an own virtual address space. VS does not allocate memory for the executable.

VS will then attach as a debugger before starting the program. So it is not "out of the picture" while executing, because it still influences the program while it runs.